# Why is MySQL is giving an incorrect count for a simple query?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(resource_id) AS num
FROM resources_authors
WHERE author_id=1657
```

This returns the result '75', which is correct.

If I change the query to only search for distinct ids:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT resource_id) AS num
FROM resources_authors
WHERE author_id=1657
```

I get a lower result of '74', which is incorrect.

However, **the table as a unique index on resource_id**, and I have checked and double-checked that there is no duplicate data.  For example, I've run:

```
SELECT resource_id, COUNT(resource_id) AS c
FROM resources_authors
WHERE author_id =1657
GROUP BY resource_id
ORDER BY c DESC
```

Even more oddly, if I add a `LIMIT` to the incorrect query, it then returns the correct result! So:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT resource_id)
FROM resources_authors
WHERE author_id=1657
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

correctly returns 75.

Have I hit a bug, or am I misunderstanding something? This is an INNODB table, MySQL 5.5.24 on Windows.

Comment: How many rows are returned if you don't use `COUNT()`? `SELECT resource_id AS num FROM resources_authors WHERE author_id-1657` ?

Comment: Is resource_id the *only* column in the unique key?  Is it nullable, and if so, are any of the values null?

Comment: First, I find it suspicious that a table called `resources_authors` has a unique index only on `resource_id`.  Second, this behavior (as you describe it) is very peculiar.  Are you sure the table was not modified between query runs?

Comment: Referring to the mysql manual 
[link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) it states that:

**COUNT(expr)**
Returns a count of the number of non-NULL values of expr in the rows retrieved by a SELECT statement. The 

COUNT(*) is somewhat different in that it returns a count of the number of rows retrieved, whether or not they contain NULL values.

**COUNT(DISTINCT expr,[expr...])**
Returns a count of the number of rows with different non-NULL expr values.

Are you sure you were not using `count(*)` instead. Can you confirm if you have any null values?

Comment: The unique index is actually a unique index of the two columns `resource_id` and `author_id` bound together. The effect is identical, of course.

No columns are nullable. I am running this on localhost, and am 100% sure that the data isn't being modified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a [known MySQL bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70038). The fix is noted in 5.5.35, 5.6.15, and 5.7.3 changelogs.